# Writing a hashtag to a file

Tags: python, string, bash

I am using a python script to create a shell script that I would ideally like to annotate with comments. If I want to add strings with hashtags in them to a code section like this:

```
with open(os.path.join("location","filename"),"w") as f:
    file = f.read()

file += """my_function() {{
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo "Please supply an argument"
return
fi
echo "argument is $1"
}}
"""
with open(os.path.join("location","filename"),"w") as f:
    f.write(file)
```

what is the best way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a `#` character in that string literal, in `$#`, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Python considers a `"""` string literal as one big string, newlines, comment-esque sequences and all, as you've noticed, until the ending `"""`.

To also pass escape characters (e.g. `\n` as `\n`, not a newline) through raw, you'd use `r"""..."""`.

In other words, with

```
with open("x", "w") as f:
    f.write("""x
hi # hello world
""")
```

you end up with a file containing

```
x
hi # hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of your wider goal, to write a file with a bash function file from a Python script seems a little wayward.

This is not really a reliable practise, if your use case specifically requires you to define a bash function via script, please explain your use case further. A cleaner way to do this would be:

Define an .sh file and read contents in from there:

```
# function.sh

my_function() {{
 # Some code
}}
```

Then in your script:

```
with open('function.sh', 'r') as function_fd:
 # Opened in 'append' mode so that content is automatically appended
 with open(os.path.join("location","filename"), "a") as target_file: 
   target_file.write(function_fd.read())
```